# Need a query to display in a particular format

Tags: mysql

I have two tables `u` and `marklist`:

```
SELECT * from u;
+------+-------+--------+-------+------------+
| id   | name  | adress | class | DOB        |
+------+-------+--------+-------+------------+
|    1 | Arun  | kollam |     6 | 1993-02-01 |
|    2 | Anoop | kollam |     6 | 1993-05-11 |
|    2 | Devi  | kollam |     6 | 1993-04-16 |
+------+-------+--------+-------+------------+

3 rows in set (0.02 sec)
 select * from marklist;
+------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
| id   | subject   | markscored | outof | userid |
+------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
|    1 | biology   |         37 |    50 |      1 |
|    2 | chemistry |         48 |    50 |      1 |
|    3 | physics   |         48 |    50 |      1 |
|    4 | biology   |         45 |    50 |      2 |
|    5 | chemistry |         41 |    50 |      2 |
|    6 | physics   |         34 |    50 |      2 |
|    7 | biology   |         39 |    50 |      3 |
|    8 | chemistry |         46 |    50 |      3 |
|    9 | physics   |         48 |    50 |      3 |
+------+-----------+------------+-------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And from this two tables I require an output as:

```
+------+------+---------+-----------+---------+----------------+------------+
| name |class | biology | chemistry | physics | totlmarkscored | percentage |
+------+------+---------+-----------+---------+----------------+------------+
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: It looks straight forward join...

Comment: look into  `join` ...`join`...`join`

Comment: with conditional aggregation

Comment: SELECT  u.name,u.class,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'biology' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS biology,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'chemistry' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS chemistry,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'physics' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS physics,
SUM( markscored) AS TOTAL,
SUM(outof) AS OUTOF
FROM  u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.userid
GROUP BY u.name,u.class;by using  the above query i get my required output........

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u.name, u.class, marklist.subject as biology, marklist.subject as chemistry, marklist.subject as physics, marklist.totlmarkscored, marklist.percentage
FROM u
INNER JOIN marklist
ON u.id=marklist.id
```

Feel free to edit my mistakes!

Comment: LOL ... there is no column present named `totlmarkscored`. that's a calculated column mate

Comment: he can use marksscored as totlmarkscored :p

Comment: Repeating `marklist.subject` in the `SELECT` list will not automatically pivot the table.

Comment: thank you all for helping me.....

Comment: SELECT  u.name,u.class,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'biology' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS biology,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'chemistry' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS chemistry,
SUM(CASE WHEN subject LIKE 'physics' THEN markscored ELSE 0 END) AS physics,
SUM( markscored) AS TOTAL,
SUM(outof) AS OUTOF
FROM  u, marklist m
WHERE u.id=m.userid
GROUP BY u.name,u.class;

Comment: by using the above query i get my output

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.name,
       t1.class,
       t2.biology,
       t2.chemistry,
       t2.physics,
       COALESCE(t2.biology, 0) + COALESCE(t2.chemistry, 0) +
           COALESCE(t2.physics, 0) AS totlmarkscored,
       100*(COALESCE(t2.biology, 0) + COALESCE(t2.chemistry, 0) +
           COALESCE(t2.physics, 0)) /
       (COALESCE(t2.outofbiology, 0) + COALESCE(t2.outofchemstry, 0) +
        COALESCE(t2.outofphysics, 0)) AS percentage
FROM u t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT userid,
           MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'biology'   THEN markscored END) AS biology,
           MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'biology'   THEN outof END)      AS outofbiology,
           MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'chemistry' THEN markscored END) AS chemistry,
           MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'chemistry' THEN outof END)      AS outofchemistry,
           MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'physics'   THEN markscored END) AS physics,
           MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'physics'   THEN outof END)      AS outofphysics,
    FROM marklist
    GROUP BY userid
) t2
    ON t1.id = t2.userid
```

Comment: thank you sir..................

Comment: SIR I M GETTING AN ERROR AS:                                     ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use n
ear ') AS biology,
           MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'biology'   THEN outof)      AS' at line 16

Comment: PLS REPLY...........

Comment: @Gowrisankar Sorry I had a few typos in there.

Comment: could you pls correct it sir?

Comment: sir pls help me ............